# Any disadvantages to calling keepSynced on same ref multiple times?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Due to the flow of my app I'm forced to call `keepSynced(true)` on the same ref every time the user opens the app. I was wondering if it's bad to do so or if Firebase just ignores any redundant `keepSynced()` calls on the same ref.

How about calling `keepSynced(true)` on a sub-ref of a ref you already called `keepSynced(true)` on, are those ignored too?

I'm really looking for a conclusive answer.

Comment: What type of  `EventListener`(s) does your app incorporate? Do you mind updating your original post with a bit of code. This could help myself or others give a more detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

keeySynced is either on or off for a path given by a reference.  There is no "multiple keepSynced" state - that would be pointless to implement inside the SDK since there is no advantage to doing so.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know it doesn't subscribe to a path twice or something

Comment: If it did, I'm sure it would be documented that way.  But like I said, there would be no reason to implement it that way, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call `keepSynced(true)` once. The way I implement it is to extend the `Application` Class.

```
public class GlobalApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a node ensures that the Firebase Database client will synchronize that node whenever it has a connection to the database servers. There is no built-in API to keep a node synchronized when there is no such connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
keepSynced(true);
```

will be useful if we enable offline support

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

If we set keepSynced(true), then whenever a user's internet connection is online, it will update it's node data. More explanation can be read in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache)

For example : if other user delete the node, than if another user offline. The offline user data will still exist if we're not setting the keepSynced(true).
In some case it will make a force close.

So My conclusion is, either we didn't support offline database, 
or support offline but with keepSynced(true). There is also another option, we can choose whenever to keepSynced true or false.